# How to access parent window which contains modal from iframe which opens in that modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html page named parent.html which has Bootstrap accordion. By clicking a link on accordion, it calls in another page search.html and opens the iframe on a modal.

search.html has a button "finish" whose functionality is to close the modal, post data on the accordion, and accordion should remain open.

I tried .opener(). It didn't seem to work. Any pointers??

## parent.html

Shop for Florist  
       
           
    
       Find Florist

```
$(function () {
    $("*[data-modal]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf('#') != 0) {
            $('<div id="searchBox" class="modal bigModal" data-backdrop="static"><div class="searchModal-header gutter10-lr"><button type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button></div><div class=""><iframe id="search" src="' + href + '" class="searchModal-body"></iframe></div></div>').modal();
        }
    });
});
```

## search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body id="detail">
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmdetail" name="frmdetail" action="preferences"  method="POST">
<div class="row-fluid gutter10-tb border-t">
   <a class="btn btn-primary my-list" href="#">Finish</a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        if (top === window) {
            alert("this page is not in an iframe");
        } else {
            alert ("Im here");
            $('.my-list').click(function(){
                alert("Im clicked");
            $('.modal', opener.document).dialog('close');
        });
        }
    });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with postMessage:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

You should send a command from search.html to the main page and let the main page handle the event of a received message.

You'll find what you need in the links above

Example (Parent page):

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    //Here is the data that you receive from search.html
    var DataReceived = e.data;
    var OriginUrl = e.origin;

    //Do what you want when the message is received
};
```

Example (search.html):

```
function buttonClick() {
    var curDomain = location.protocol + '//' + location.host; //This will be received as e.origin (see above)
    var commandString = "Hello parent page!"; //This will be received as e.data
    parent.postMessage(commandString,curDomain); //Sends message to parent frame
}
```

The windows.onmessage in the parent page should be 'launched' on page load. The 'buttonClick()' function could be called when and where you want to send a message to the parent page that will execute some stuff (in this case your stuff with accordion)

EDIT:
to close the modal try this way:

Parent:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    //Here is the data that you receive from search.html
    var DataReceived = e.data;
    var OriginUrl = e.origin;
    if (e.data == 'close') {
        $(this).modal('hide'); //Example code, you can run what you want
    }
};
```

Search:

```
function buttonClick() {
    var curDomain = location.protocol + '//' + location.host; //This will be received as e.origin (see above)
    var commandString = "close"; //This will be received as e.data
    parent.postMessage(commandString,curDomain); //Sends message to parent frame
}
```

In this case you send the message 'close' to the parent frame. When parent receive the message he check if it's "close" and then run the code you want (in this case you close your modal with $(".modal").dialog('close'))

Comment: so if I have to close modal on parent window, do I have to in child html page: parent.postmessage(modal.('close'), curDomain;

Comment: check the new example! remember that you send a message with a data (in this case 'close') and when the parent receive this message you can run all the code you want. You can also set more commands other than 'close'.

Comment: http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/exchangeux/personal/parent.html - couldn't get it to work..what am i missing??

Comment: the script works, you have only to replace $(".modal").dialog('close'); with $('.modal').modal('hide'); and it will work!